# How can I get url params in angular controller on a rails app?

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this url in my rails app:

http://localhost:4000/en/events/sunrise-trip/dashboard

How can I get the event id params using in an AngularJs controller?

my app.coffee file:

```
@app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'templates'
])

@app.config([
  '$httpProvider', '$ngRoute', ($httpProvider)->
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]')
])
@app.run(->
  console.debug 'angular running'
)
```

my bower file

```
asset 'bootstrap'
asset 'moment'
asset 'lodash'
asset 'angular'
asset 'angular-route'
```

my rails app.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
// require select2
//= require angular
//= require angular-route
//= require bootstrap
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like

```
@app.controller "ticketsCtrl", ($scope, $routeParams)->
  $scope.event = SomeEventService.retrieve($routeParams.eventId)
```

Answer (score 0):

to manipulate values in the URL you need `ngRoute` . So you need to use [angular-route](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route) in your application . then you can inject `$routeParams` to your controller .

say you have a url like this `.when('paramas/:paramId1/:paramId2')` , you can use like following to access the parameters

```
function MyController($scope, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams.paramId1);
    console.log($routeParams.paramId2)
};
```

Comment: Here is my app
`@app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'templates'
])

@app.config([
  '$httpProvider', '$route', ($httpProvider)->
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]')
])
@app.run(->
  console.debug 'angular running'
)`

I get an exception saying app couldn't init because of unknown provider ngRoute

Comment: Hi guys, any news about this question?